# Unit test that is checking that child object fields have been populated on the parent object fields

Tags: apex, unit-test

Here is my class for trigger that populates the custom fields on Opportunity when the custom object Property is created and unit test for it which shows the following message:

> Trigger.copyPropEscrowAddressOnExchange: line 7, column 1: [] 17:58:38.2 (620530709)|USER_DEBUG|[35]|DEBUG|DmlSystem.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, copyPropEscrowAddressOnExchange: execution of AfterInsert
>
> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Please help me to resolve the issue. I've researched the same issues on the other forums and haven't gotten a clear answer.

```java
public with sharing class PropertyEscrowContactOnExchange {
public static void copyPropertyEscrowAddressOnExchange(List<Property__c> propList) {

    List<Id> oppIds = new List<Id>();
    Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (Property__c prop : propList) {
        if (prop.Escrow_Company__c != null) {
            accIds.add(prop.Escrow_Company__c);
            oppIds.add(prop.Opportunity__c);
        }

        Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunities = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([
                SELECT Id, Name, Escrow_Company__c, Escrow_Address__c, Escrow_City__c, Escrow_State__c, Escrow_Zip_Code__c
                FROM Opportunity
                WHERE Id IN :oppIds
        ]);

        List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

        for (Property__c p : propList) {
            Opportunity o = opportunities.get(p.Opportunity__c);
                o.Escrow_Company__c = p.Escrow_Company__c;
                o.Escrow_Address__c = p.Escrow_Address__c;
                o.Escrow_City__c = p.Escrow_City__c;
                o.Escrow_State__c = p.Escrow_State__c;
                o.Escrow_Zip_Code__c = p.Escrow_Zip_Code__c;
            oppsToUpdate.add(o);
        }
        update oppsToUpdate;
    }
```

---

```
 @IsTest
private class PropertyEscrowAddressTest {

    @IsTest
    static void testPropertyEscrowAddressCopiedOnExchange() {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = acc.IsEscrow__c;
        acc.Name = 'ABM';
        insert acc;

        Opportunity opps = new Opportunity();
        opps.Name = 'testOppABC';
        opps.AccountId = acc.Id;
        opps.CloseDate = System.today();
        opps.StageName = 'Exchange Completed';
        insert opps;

        Property__c prop = new Property__c();
        prop.Name = '123 Str';
        prop.Escrow_Company__c = acc.IsEscrow__c;
        prop.Opportunity__c = opps.Id;
        prop.Escrow_Address__c = '456 Sun Str';
        prop.Escrow_City__c = 'Seattle';
        prop.Escrow_State__c = 'Washington';
        prop.Escrow_Zip_Code__c = '98765';

        Test.startTest();
        try{
            insert prop;
        }catch (DmlException e){
            System.debug('Dml' + e);
        }

        try{
            update opps;
        }catch (DmlException e){
            System.debug('Dml' + e);
        }
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(opps.Escrow_Company__c, prop.Escrow_Company__c);

    }
```

Comment: The error message you've included seems to mention line 7, but in a trigger that you haven't included. Is that the full text of the error message? Are there any other lines indicated in the stack trace?

Comment: You should remove the exception handlers from your unit test. Exceptions thrown in unit tests should help you locate the problem.

Comment: As an aside, those try/catch statements in your test class are counterproductive. Swallowing exceptions like that (using system.debug() and then trying to continue on) is bad practice and can lead to all manner of hard to debug errors. If you get an exception in a test method, that's something that you _want_ to cause the test to fail (except in very specific circumstances). Exceptions are usually pretty good at telling you where the issue is too.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two serious bugs in this code.

```
    for (Property__c prop : propList) {
        if (prop.Escrow_Company__c != null) {
            accIds.add(prop.Escrow_Company__c);
            oppIds.add(prop.Opportunity__c);
        }

        Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunities = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([
                SELECT Id, Name, Escrow_Company__c, Escrow_Address__c, Escrow_City__c, Escrow_State__c, Escrow_Zip_Code__c
                FROM Opportunity
                WHERE Id IN :oppIds
        ]);
```

The `for` loop should be closed *before* the query. Everything after the `if` statement is intended to take place *outside* the query for bulkification purposes.

```
        for (Property__c p : propList) {
            Opportunity o = opportunities.get(p.Opportunity__c);
                o.Escrow_Company__c = p.Escrow_Company__c;
                o.Escrow_Address__c = p.Escrow_Address__c;
                o.Escrow_City__c = p.Escrow_City__c;
                o.Escrow_State__c = p.Escrow_State__c;
                o.Escrow_Zip_Code__c = p.Escrow_Zip_Code__c;
            oppsToUpdate.add(o);
        }
```

`o` is `null`, presumably because `p.Opportunity__c` is `null`. You need to check for nulls here, not above where you check `prop.Escrow_Company__c` for nullity (it doesn't particularly matter if the `Id` is `null` there, because a query for `Id = null` will return no values).